# Reproducing Fully-Connected Sequential Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, customization

I want to better understand how to make custom keras layers but I can't seem to find the following online.... I'm looking to learn how to reproduct the basic (feed-forward) keras layer using the custom layers construction.

Where can I find this online or how do I do it?

I ask since all online resources that I came across only do other simpler layers as examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subclass the `tf.keras.layers.Layer` class. The `SimpleDense` layer is given as an example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer).